# How to copy files (in sequence) from remote server to local path using Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

If i have some 100 files on a remote server path. I want to copy files to local using C# using `Parallel.ForEach` which will copy files in parallel but should copy in sequence or order by name so that WPF application will not wait for all the images to copy to show in the thumbnail grid.

Eg:

```
File1
File2
File3
```

This is the code which I am using which will copy files in parallel but one thread copies first set files and one thread copies files from the end. I want to copy files in parallel but in sequence.

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;                
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    Parallel.ForEach(StackImageCollection, po, (currentFile) =>
    {
        string[] destFile = currentFile.Source.Split('\\');
        string destFileName = destFile.LastOrDefault();               
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile.Source);
        string tempFileName = Path.Combine((Path.GetTempPath()), "ScanQC_temp"+"\\"+destItemName+"\\"+ destFileName);

        if (!File.Exists(tempFileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Copy(ActualScanPath + "//" + fileName, tempFileName);
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(ImageCollectionInfo.FindIndex(c => c.ItemName == currentFile.ItemName));

            if (index != -1)
            {
                ((BoImage)ImageCollectionInfo[index]).IsCopied = true;
            }
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Well, you can put file names into queue (in preferred order) and make copy threads dequeue them from it. But even if copy operations will be started in order you wish, they may finish in different order. Also, what makes you think that copying files in parallel would be any faster than copying them in sequence? The network bandwidth is just the same, it would only increase the fragmentation of your file system.

Comment: Actually my WPF application will show first 16 images (We can change how many images to show).If i press PageDown it will show next 16 images and so on .SO i want images to copy in parallel but in sequence so that User will not be interrupted to see images (user will not wait for all the images to copy )

Comment: I think you're mixing "copy in parallel" with "copy in background" here. I don't think parallel copying here will give any speed up, so just copy them in sequence on background thread.

Comment: Yes ,I need to do in background in parallel to copy files faster but in sequence.So Parallel.ForEach or TPL in C#4.0 cant be used for this?

Comment: I can understand wanting to download as many images as possible at a time (they could be coming from different remote sources). What is causing an issue for me is when you indicate you want to force a sequence on the parallel tasks. That will introduce an artificial block. What @AlexSkalozub suggested will make the downloads start in the order you want. You can't guarantee that the tasks will finish in the correct sequence since you are dependent on the remote resources to cooperate (they won't), regardless of individual file size.

Comment: @Martin Soles/Alex Skalozub,Could you Please suggest if i can use Task Parallel library here?.If so Please provide code to put file names to queue using TPL

Comment: @MartinSoles - Could you Please suggest if i can use Task Parallel library here?.If so Please provide code to put file names to queue using TPL

Comment: @AlexSkalozub - Please provide code if this is not correct way to do